# How to make check on args in bash and execute some command if a sertain argument was not set?

Tags: bash

I know how to give default values to arguments in bash or exit with an error message if one is unset. (from [here](http://linuxgazette.net/18/bash.html))

I want to make check if an argument was set, execute some code if it wasn't and the exit.

```
if [$1 is not set]; then
  execute command
fi
```

I am writing a wrapper around another command. It has it's own usage message if no first argument is set (it is actually an input filename). It has other inputs that I am hardcoding for now. The actual command in the bash script is something like :

```
command $1 12 3124 534
```

I want to invoke it's own help message if no $1 was sent to the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check the length of arguments:

```
if (( $# < 1 )); then
    echo 'There are no arguments, so you can bet that $1 was not set.'
fi
```

It's usually trivial to check if a variable has a non-empty value in shell:

```
[ -n "$val" ]
```

However, if you want to determine if a name has been *declared* I'll refer you to [BashFAQ 83](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/083)

Comment: if $1 has to be also a filename, use `[ -r "$1" ] || { echo "Error 1: you shuold provide a (readable) filename : $0 filename. I STOP HERE" ; exit 1 ; }` . See `man test` for other usefull tests. And on recent shells, `[[` is even better (in bash: `help '[['`)